# Как работать с join с сводными таблицами?

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, join

у меня не получается сджойнить таблицы что бы результат меня устраивал (

Вот sql который я использую:

```
select
`animes`.*,
`anime_accesses`.`slug` as `access_slug`,
`animes__accesses`.`created_at` as `access_created_at`
from `animes`
inner join `animes__accesses` on `animes`.`uuid` = `animes__accesses`.`anime_uuid`
inner join `anime_accesses` on `animes__accesses`.`access_uuid` = `anime_accesses`.`uuid`
```

И вот результат:
[image: Result]

Как вы можете видеть у айтемов есть уровни доступа, в данный момент у одного айтема есть два уровня Новый и Модерация при чём Модерация это более новый уровень (по дате создания) и мне нужно что бы брался последний уровень доступа)

Таблицы которые я использую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добился желаемого результата следующим sql запросом )

```
select
`animes`.*,
`anime_accesses`.`slug` as `access_slug`,
`animes__accesses`.`created_at` as `access_created_at`
from `animes`
inner join (
    SELECT o.*
    FROM `animes__accesses` o
    LEFT JOIN `animes__accesses` b 
        ON o.anime_uuid = b.anime_uuid 
        AND o.created_at < b.created_at
    WHERE b.created_at is NULL
) `animes__accesses` on `animes`.`uuid` = animes__accesses.`anime_uuid`
inner join `anime_accesses` on animes__accesses.`access_uuid` = `anime_accesses`.`uuid`
```

Подскажите как мне его перевести в ORM Laravel пж

Перевёл в Laravel но решение меня не усваивает (((

```
$query->whereIn('animes.uuid', (
    \Arr::pluck(
        \DB::select("
            select
            `animes`.`uuid`
            from `animes`
            inner join (
                SELECT o.*
                FROM `animes__accesses` o
                LEFT JOIN `animes__accesses` b
                    ON o.anime_uuid = b.anime_uuid
                    AND o.created_at < b.created_at
                WHERE b.created_at is NULL
            ) `animes__accesses` on `animes`.`uuid` = animes__accesses.`anime_uuid`
            inner join `anime_accesses` on animes__accesses.`access_uuid` = `anime_accesses`.`uuid`
            WHERE `anime_accesses`.`slug` = '{$r->getAccessSlug()}'
            "),'uuid'
    )
));
```

Хелп плеас)

Comment: Вопрос больше в том, а точно надо ли такой запрос городить. Если да, то переписываете методами `join()`, `leftJoin()`, `select()` `where()` с вложенностью (коллбэки) от модели `Anime`. Но скорее всего Вам просто нужно нормально связи построить в моделях, и тогда не нжуно будет джоинить всё по 10 раз.

Comment: а сделать сортировку по ````access_created_at````, сгруппировать и получите на выходе, что на каждый элемент будет выбран последний доступ.